# Google Search Console - Elements too close, but smartphone bot doesn't seem to load CSS

Tags: google-search-console

In my Google Search Console, it shows : « Elements are too close from one another », but when I see the screencapture that Google shared with me explaining the problem, it is just not loading CSS and javascript.

At the right of the image, you can see that the CSS is not being loading by Google bot, which makes the elements too close of course...

[image: printscreen]

Comment: Any clue how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Rather than trust the GSC to properly render the page and download your CSS, have you tried using the developer tools in your browser (F12) and changing the viewport to various mobile sizes?  I found that when I used the developer tools, I was able to see problems in my CSS that needed correcting.

Comment: Don't rely on Google Search Console for 100% results, test your website in different mobile devices or you can use simulators if it's rendering perfectly then you don't need to do any changes. Check if CSS is available on https version or not, this is sometime an issue that I've encountered for such problems.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes, I've used the inspector tool in Chrome and Firefox, changing the viewport. It all seems to render well.

Comment: And yes CSS is available on HTTPS version.